# ISubscriber.EventHandler is not called

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have a really small server side plugin for the TFS 2015.3. I implemented and deployed it by the nice walkthrough here: https://socialtfs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20create%20and%20debug%20a%20Team%20Foundation%20Server%20server-side%20plugin

We have two completly seperated TFS 2015 instances, one for testing purposes, one for being used productively. I developed the server plugin - with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (if that is important) - on our test TFS where I could debug the plugin and it worked as intended.

However, when I deployed it to our live system, the plugin did nothing. I added some logging messages and saw that the constructor of the class that implements the ISubscriber interface is indeed called (so I assume the plugin itself is recognized and loaded by the TFS), but the EventHandler method is never called (means no log message is written).

I checked the Windows event log (under Event Viewer/Application and Service Logs/Microsoft-Team Foundation Server/Debug) but found nothing relevant.

I have only one more guess but if I am right, I need help to solve this. The live TFS was setup by someone who is not working here any longer. The test TFS was setup by me just a few days ago and with default settings. I know for sure that both versions are the Update 3 versions of TFS 2015, but I do not know if any configuration tweak (that the person who setup the live system some months ago) can cause the plugin not to work.

Can someone perhaps help me with that or has someone another idea why the plugin works on one TFS but not on the other?

Here is my class:

```
public class MyEventHandler : ISubscriber
{
    public EventHandler()
    {
        // Called from Test- and Live-TFS!
        EventLog.WriteEntry("TFS Services", "Plugin loaded");
    }

    public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(...)
    {
        // Called ONLY from Test-TFS!
        EventLog.WriteEntry("TFS Services", "Event handled");
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't see any error in the Event log which means there is not any dependency broken.

And there is no message written. Suggest you to register the "XXEvent" event source on your production TFS server.

You could use the tool [BisSubsribe](https://www.google.nl/search?q=bissubscribe&oq=bissubs&aqs=) to register for an event. It can hook up your own service to events occurring in TFS. Also give a try with rebuilding the assemblies. More details please refer the answers in this question: [TFS 2017 : ISubscriber plugin model still supported](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0644e50-887a-4bdb-9e22-37f9fefa8ada/tfs-2017-isubscriber-plugin-model-still-supported-?forum=tfsgeneral)

Moreover you could manually compare your two server settings in the **TFS Administrator Console**.

Comment: What do you mean by "register the XXEvent event source"? I want to react to the WorkItemChangedEvent, which should be registered by default, shouldn't it? And how can help BisSubscribe to execute the special code that I've written? It is not a simple "mail to fix address when a work item changed" type of stuff that I am doing.

Comment: @Crowley  Since your workitemchange ProcessEvent method is not called, but it should be. So try to register it in the new server. In the TFServer run from cmd line the event handler endpoint registration with the right event. For example: In TFS2017,

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Tools>bissubscribe /eventType WorkItemChangedEvent /address http://ENDPOINT_HOST_NAME/YOUR_SITE/YOUR_ENDPOINT.asmx /deliveryType Soap /collection http://TFS_SERVER_NAME:8080/Tfs/DefaultCollection`

Comment: Begging your pardon, but that's exactly what I do not understand. I do not have a webservice, hence no endpoint or *.asmx that I could use. I have a server side plugin that implements the ISubscriber interface. It is a .net class library (assembly) where the output is a dll. Or is there a way to register the WorkItemChangedEvent without such a web endpoint?

Comment: @Crowley Sorry for  misunderstanding. There are two ways to achieve this. One is directly within the process of tfs by implementing an ISubscriber and listening to the WorkitemChangedEvent . Another is using the client API register a wcf service to get notified for workitem changes . Seems you are using the first . The second which for registering for notifications is just a coded alternate for the BisSubsribe tool. For your way you just need to put the dll in the servers plugin folder.  Double check the path such as `C:\Program Files\M.T.F.S 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins`

Comment: @Crowley Besides,since there is no log info, suggest you to follow the steps in this blog ([Developing and debugging Server Side Event Handlers in TFS](http://blog.ehn.nu/2010/10/developing-and-debugging-server-side-event-handlers-in-tfs-2010/)) to debug the event handler, to check if the `EventLog.WriteEntry(…)` method be called and write log successfully.

Comment: The link you provided describes the same steps as the link that I provided in the OP. The dll is put into the plugin folder and it is loaded. As I said, the constructor of my class (which implements the ISubscriber interface) IS called, the event log entry is written. However, the ProcessEvent method is only called in the test TFS, not in the productive TFS. As if the productive TFS does not fire the event...